# Why treeview shifts the column dimension in row containing tree child?

Tags: .net, silverlight, grid, treeview, radtreeview

I have situtation where i have 4 rows and 3 columns where third row contains a tree (which must show child only in third row of first column) and which must show all the data properly vertically alligned (exactly below other, not left or right) in other columns as well. Like this:
[image]

But actually its not working like this it shifts the column in bit right (because of child cover some area and the data in second column and third column is shifted to right with the same distance).
Here is the view (showing the gridlines of row and column). 
You can see in the image  that in Second Row "Clearing Prices" click i have a shift of "Launch Step" (column 3) in right. That i want to allign just below each other

**In my xaml code** I have "RelatedItems" which binds the child of "Clearing Prices like"Equities, Bonds, Futures etc." whereas "EODDataStepsCollection" contains "Conversion Rates, Clearing Prices, Portfolio Evaluations".

**Why this shift in right of Buttons of 3rd column ("Launch Steps") arises.  How to sove this problem ?**

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you said it yourself child elements are shifted to the right, and that means that the whole row is shifted. You must adjust element width to align it with other tree elements.

It may be possible to try and shove in some custom sizing logic here, but that seems not reasonable because there's already a control that does that for you - [RadTreeListView](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radtreelistview-overview.html). It's basically a tree meets grid, which looks exactly like what you are doing right now.

Comment: ..Thanks . That would be great if you could please giv me a sample to make as reference. Thanks a lot. I understood nothing on the given link.

Comment: @user3085082, just read on tutorials there. Here's [Getting started](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radtreeliestview-getting-started.html) article, or if you prefer just code then visit their [TreeListView demo](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#TreeListView/FirstLook) - they have sources there available.

Comment: there is a problem in the way the column data is displayed . Yiu can see that in my code i am binding textblock and and button in columns but here there is something else "<telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Label}". In fact i done it .It displays nothing.